# Bootstrap css destroys my css

Tags: wordpress, modal-dialog, styling

I am using the Gantry Framework with wordpress.
Everything fine.
I wanted to create a modal window using Bootstrap.
I have included the bootsrap cdn from [here](http://%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20href=%22http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css%22%3E)
The problem that appears is that it overwrittes the css of my web site creating smaller fonts and so.
I tried to include it locally but again it is the minified version and i can't manage to find all the selectors.
How could i instruct wordpress to load this css before my css, so in the end the correct css is loaded and not overwritten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress's `wp_enqueue_style` method has a dependencies parameter which lets you specify which stylesheets the one your adding depends on.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'css_bootstrap', '/path-to-the-file/bootstrap.scss' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'css_gantry',    '/path-to-the-file/gantry.scss' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'css_main',      '/path-to-the-file/main.scss', array('css_bootstrap', 'css_gantry' );
```

The final parameter on the second line instructs css_main to load *AFTER* css_bootstrap and css_gantry.

After this, make sure you are paying attention to the cascading rules of CSS. It might just be that your style rules are not as specific as the ones Gantry set.

For instance:

```
.something .inner {
    color: blue;
}


.inner {
    color: red;
}
```

The text color of `.inner` will be blue, because the first rule is more specific (2 elements deep, versus 1 deep).

Comment: hi @rideron89,very interesting. So how would i instruct wordpress to load first: /path-to-the-file/bootstrap.css and then my custom stylesheet /path-to-the-file/custom.scss. Also since the Gantry framework compiles the css files which file should i point to? The .scss or the final .css?

Comment: @xbass540 I edited the answer to add the bootstrap CSS file. If you look at the 3rd line of the first code segment, you will see an extra array() parameter. This parameter tells WordPress to load your stylesheet after the other two stylesheets. And compiles SCSS on the run, so include the SCSS file here. I'm not too familiar with Gantry, but make sure you aren't loading Bootstrap twice.

Comment: Ok @xbass540, the more I think about it, I don't think my answer is the soltuion to your problem. I don't think you need to worry about the load order of the CSS files. Rather, you should focus on making sure your styles have a higher CSS specificity. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) is some more info.

Comment: i will check everything and let you know but for sure this describes the best approach to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite `CSS properties` by using the `!important` statement. `!important` overwrites any normal `CSS` assigned to lets say a paragraph. Example:

```css
p.paragraph {
color: red;
}

p.paragraph {
color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<p class="paragraph">
  Hello
</p>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Like I say this is a whole finished website, this means that I will have to !important numerous entries and test for days. i was hoping to load bootstrap before my css

Comment: I'd like to add that i have tried to !important some rules and this doesn't help unfortunatelly.

Comment: @xbass540 if you want to load bootstrap before you're normal `CSS` and you'd like that bootstrap overrules some of your `CSS` then try deleting the parts of your `CSS` that you'd like bootstrap to take over

Comment: hi,like i say on my initial message the Bootstrap css is minified and i can't really find the rules it overrides and delete them (i think this is what you mean). Also maybe you didnt understand correctly: I dont want to override my styles with Bootstrap. I just want to use the modal functionality of Bootstrap and nothing else

Comment: @xbass540 i think i understand what you're trying to imply. I think that you should lookup the non minified `CSS` files of bootstrap. Change them and then minify them and include them as a library. Source files of bootstrap can be found [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/#source-files) and [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap)

Comment: ok going this way i will have to check all pages and find out any issues. I tried though and called the bootstrap.css locally. Now the page freezes. Isn't bootstrap.css enough to display a modal window? Should i inclyde more than that? The console is empty.

Comment: Best thing to do for loading the bootstrap library is by loading the `CSS` of bootstrap and the `JS` of bootstrap. both minified or normal is completely your choise. @xbass540

Comment: i can't get it. If i loadthe CSS from the minified version of the CDN everything works fine and i dont need the JS file. If i download it locally everything brakes. Why should i use the JS file as well now, since until now i wasn't using it?

Comment: the `bootstrap.(min).js` file isn't required but it can come in handy because it's one file that contains all the posible plug-ins of bootstrap. A more further description you're able to find [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/)

Answer (score -1):

What I did to solve the problem is that I used `!important` to correct all rules that had been affected by loading bootstrap on top of my theme's CSS. I had to correct multiple CSS rules but in the end all looks fine now.